# What are the editor options/extensions available to have same keyboard shotcuts on Windows/Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, vim, emacs, ide

I switch between operating systems based on work enviroinment. But I don't want to remember different keyboard shortcuts for different operating systems, editors. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: in VSC you can add a vim extension to use vim shortcuts, or use VSC on all platforms, for Linux and Windows the key bindings are the same

Answer (score 1):

The disparity you are dealing with has multiple causes. One is that operating systems have different keybindings and even keyboard layouts so cross-platform native applications—or cross-platform applications that try to feel native—will inevitably have different shortcuts on different systems. Ctrl versus Cmd for starters. On top of that, you are using different applications which, beyond the basic cut/paste/undo/etc., have different shortcuts anyway.

From there, you can explore a few roads.

One road is to remap your keyboard entirely at the system level. There are programs for that on both platforms and it might work if you use the same external keyboard on all systems.

Another road is to do that remapping at the application level. Look for configuration options or third-party extensions.

And another road is to choose a single application that ignores platform conventions. Technically, Vim and Emacs fit the bill because they have been living in their own bubbles for decades but switching from full-fledged GUI IDEs to TUI editors is a hell of a challenge that will require a lot of effort learning, and unlearning. Neither are really designed for being IDEs so, before taking that road, I would suggest you think long and hard about it.

FWIW, I have been using Vim as my main driver for a little more than a decade but I don't treat it as an IDE because a) I know full well it can't be one no matter how hard you try to disguise it, and b) I didn't need one for my daily work anyway. YMMV.